# Connection to voltdb within container fails with connection refused

Tags: docker, sqlcmd, voltdb

According to the information on docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/r/voltdb/voltdb-community/) I was able to start the three nodes after adding the nodenames to my /etc/hosts file. Commands I executed:

```
docker pull voltdb/voltdb-community:latest

docker network create -d bridge voltLocalCluster
docker run -d -P -e HOST_COUNT=3 -e HOSTS=node1,node2,node3 --name=node1 --network=voltLocalCluster voltdb/voltdb-community:latest
docker run -d -P -e HOST_COUNT=3 -e HOSTS=node1,node2,node3 --name=node2 --network=voltLocalCluster voltdb/voltdb-community:latest
docker run -d -P -e HOST_COUNT=3 -e HOSTS=node1,node2,node3 --name=node3 --network=voltLocalCluster voltdb/voltdb-community:latest
docker exec -it node1 bash

sqlcmd
> Output:
Unable to connect to VoltDB cluster
    localhost:21212 - Connection refused
```

According to log files the voltdb has started and is running normally.
Does anyone have an idea why the connection is refused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow the given example and fix your `HOSTS` argument.

It should be `HOSTS=node1,node2,node3` instead of yours, thus you let your service know about all nodes in cluster.

Comment: Thanks a lot, even though this was not the issue in my case because I had the parameters correct in my VM. I corrected the data on stackoverflow. 
Funny: You're answer is correct too, because the wrong parameters in the earlier post lead to the issue. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There might exists a bug in the docker-entrypoint.sh I don't see yet because I shouldn't need to connect into the container and run these commands manually, but doing this solved my issue:

```
docker exec -it node1 bash
voltdb init
voltdb start
```